# Send file from PHP page to another

Tags: php, file-upload

I need to send a file from one PHP page (on which client uploads their files) to another PHP page on another server were files will be finaly stored.

To comunicate now I use JSON-RPC protocol; is it wise to send the file this way?

```
$string = file_get_contents("uploaded_file_path");
```

send the string to remote server and then

```
file_put_contents("file_name", $recieved_string_from_remte);
```

I understand that this approach takes twice the time than uploading directly to the second server.

Thanks

[edit]

**details:**

i need to write a service allowing some php (may be joomla) user to use a simple api to upload files and send some other data to my server which analyze them , put in a db and send back a response

[re edit]

**i need to create a Simple method allowing the final user to do that, who will use this the interface on server 1 (the uploading) use the php and stop, so remote ssh mount ore strange funny stuff**

Comment: yep, i think u need a better approuch, that's can be extremely dangerous or critic. Maybe trought ftp or sql. But if u still need do that, i answer you...

Comment: the problem is that 1-i don't want to add extra stuff, 2- the remote srv need to do some stuff whit this file and sand back some response , in object oriented context, so i don't want to fragment the operation

Comment: http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/ in my experience this tends to be the traditional choice when passing between scripts.

Comment: @Leandro why dangerous? i think to check md5 to verify the integrity of transfer, you see other potential problems?

Comment: i think the better you can work (but its hard if you never work with it) is using socket where you can controll the packets and fragments of the file)

Comment: i mean with dangeours not in security, if not in the integrity of the system. Did you think in the time out operations of doing this? Requirements and bandwith/memory resources from multiple process?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I were you, I'd send the file directly to the second server and store its file name and/or some hash of the file name (for easier retrieval) in a database on the first server.

Using this approach, you could query the second server from the first one for the status of the operation. This way, you can leave the file processing to the second machine, and assign user interaction to the first machine.

Comment: To add to what Pateman is saying, you can always base64 encode it, store the encoded string in sql, and have the two servers work of the same database. In order to get it to jumpstart the second server I recommend shooting the second server (page) a post command with an ID value of the entry in the sql database, so it knows what to look for. If the string IS large (your 25mb limit mentioned below) break the string into parts and have the second server assemble them. Takes load off your primary server and lets the second to the work.

Comment: the db is connected only to the second server, and the files will be up to 25MB so it will be too huge to the db i think

Comment: 25mb is not to big (we have 1gb entries in our db), especially if you break up the string. Plus its extremely easy to set up sql communications across ips/domains. Create a user who has access from xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx ip, give them exclusive rights to the db or table, then set up your mysql_connect to use whatever the ip of the second server is, and the user/pass you created for rights. ;)

Answer (score 1):

As i said in my comment, THIS IS NOT RECOMMENDABLE but anyway....

You can use sockets reading byte by byte:
http://php.net/manual/en/book.sockets.php

or you can use ftp: 
http://php.net/manual/en/book.ftp.php

Anyway, the problem in your approuch is doing the process async or sync with the user navigation? I really suggest you passed it by sql or ftp and give the user a response based on another event (like a file watching, then email, etc) or using sql (binary, blob, etc)

Comment: the files can be up to 25megas so sql approache is exludes, i'll take a look at the sokets

Comment: you can zip them into a blob (what kind of sql server are you using, mssql, mysql?) You can save a url and try to read it with a called process from the other server? I dont know, trying to not finish in socket. Of course you can do it with sockets but is very work/time expensive.

Comment: the db is mysql, the files are already in a compressed format, i don't want to leave them on the upload server because the upload server will handle only the interface to the service, and don't need to care about files

Comment: i understand now with the detailed information what do you need. Well, is there a lot of work around here but i think you can bet your solution in the better performance. Sure you thinked it but... can you get do the "validation" or "analysis" before you upload the file to the final destination? It can be more quick for the response to the user. If not, you can't think it without take 2 times. First upload to the temp, second upload the temp to the server.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need the files immediately after receiving them (for processing etc), then you can save them all in one folder on Server 1 and set up a cron to scp the contents of the folder to Server 2. All this assuming you are using linux servers, this is one of the most secure and efficient ways to do it.

For more info please take a look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_copy or google scp.

Comment: hey, as somebody has already mentioned, your safest bet is to inverse the whole thing, submit the form to Server 2 (given that it's publicly accessible), it saves the file, strips the form data and passes the data to Server 1, it's much easier and faster that way, then just settle on a way to pass the data from S2 to S1, simple REST will do

Answer (score 1):

Use SSHFS on machine 1 to map a file path to machine 2 (using SSH) and save the uploaded file to machine 2. After the file is uploaded, trigger machine 2 to do the processing and report back as normal.

This would allow you to upload to machine 1, but actually stream it to machine 2's HD so it can be processed faster on that machine.

This will be faster than any SQL or manual file copy solution, because the file transfer happens while the user is uploading the file.